# How to properly define a function pointer in struct, which takes struct as a pointer?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I have a struct with a callback function, the callback function needs a pointer to the structure in order to do its operation. How do I properly define these elements such that is will compile without warnings?

```
typedef struct {

    // some fields required for processing...

    int (*doAction)(struct pr_PendingResponseItem *pr);
} pr_PendingResponseItem;
```

If I remove the "struct" attribute on the pr parameter, I get an error. If I leave it in, I get a warning:
"its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want"

It all works, but I would like to know the proper way to define such a structure.

Also related, is defining a self referential structure:

```
typedef struct LinkedItem_ {
    LinkedItem_ * prev;
    LinkedItem_ * next;
    void * data;
} LinkedItem;
```

(I think this is correct, but additional thoughts are welcome if it is related to the question.)

Answer (score 13):

Your function pointer references a struct pr_PendingResponseItem, but you haven't declared a struct pr_PendingResponseItem. You just have an unnamed structure typedef'ed to the name pr_PendingResponseItem (and that name isn't established yet).

Give the struct a name:

```
struct pr_PendingResponseItem {

    // some fields required for processing...

    int (*doAction)(struct pr_PendingResponseItem *pr);
} ;
typedef struct pr_PendingResponseItem pr_PendingResponseItem;
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to do it — for both your example structures.  They are essentially isomorphic.

1. Use a structure tag, as already shown in various other answers.

   ```
   typedef struct pr_PendingResponseItem
   {
       // some fields required for processing...
       int (*doAction)(struct pr_PendingResponseItem *pr);
   } pr_PendingResponseItem;

   typedef struct LinkedItem
   {
       struct LinkedItem *prev;
       struct LinkedItem *next;
       void * data;
   } LinkedItem;
   ```
2. Use `typedef` to give a name to an incomplete structure type and use the `typedef` in the structure definition.

   ```
   typedef struct pr_PendingResponseItem pr_PendingResponseItem;
   struct pr_PendingResponseItem
   {
       // some fields required for processing...
       int (*doAction)(pr_PendingResponseItem *pr);
   };

   typedef struct LinkedItem LinkedItem;
   struct LinkedItem
   {
       LinkedItem *prev;
       LinkedItem *next;
       void * data;
   };
   ```

Note that the structure tags are in a different namespace from the `typedef` names, so there is no need to use different names for the `typedef` and structure tag.  Also note that in C++ the `typedef` would be unnecessary.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually identified that you could forward declare the `typedef`.

Answer (score 4):

something like this

```
typedef struct _pr_PendingResponseItem_ {

    // some fields required for processing...

    int (*doAction)(struct _pr_PendingResponseItem_ *pr);
} pr_PendingResponseItem;
```

should fix it.

(Tested & works)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by nos above.

The key insight here is that when dealing with a declaration like "typedef struct name1 {} name2;", you are actually declaring two types i.e. "**struct name1** {};" and then "typedef struct name1 **name2**;", where "**struct name1**" is a type and you have to use the syntax "struct name1" to refer to it, and "**name2**" is a type, and you refer to it as "name2". You are allowed to leave "name1" out, in which case you just define the second type and the first one remains a anonymous struct.

Now, in the first case, if you want to refer to the type "struct pr_PendingResponseItem", you need to declare that type, instead of the anonymous struct you have declared. So, change your struct declaration to "struct pr_PendingResponseItem".

In the second case, you are trying to refer to a struct type as a forward reference (i.e. referring to it before its definition is complete), which is allowed, but to refer to a struct type, the required syntax is "struct name". So you need to replace forward references to "LinkedItem_" in your definition with "struct LinkedItem_".