# Error when defining a struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am attempting to write a simple linked list just for practice and to jog my memory a little bit, but I have ran into trouble.  I am pretty inexperienced in C, and I don't understand why this isn't working.  I am trying to define a Node and a LinkedList struct, but every time I try to compile I get an error saying Node is an unknown type.  I'm sure I am missing something, but I can't figure this out.  Thanks all!

This is my ll.h file

```
  1 #ifndef ll_h
  2 #define ll_h
  3 
  4 #include <stdio.h>
  5 
  6 typedef struct {
  7     void *data;
  8     Node *next;
  9     Node *prev;
 10 } Node;
 11 
 12 
 13 typedef struct {
 14     Node *first;
 15     Node *last;
 16     int size;
 17 } LinkedList;
 18 
 19 
 20 void *getData(LinkedList list, int index);
 21 int getSize(LinkedList list);
 22 void *deleteNode(LinkedList, int index);
 23 void add(LinkedList list, void *data);
 24 void freeList(LinkedList list);
 25 
 26 #endif
```

Errors I am receiveing

```
cc -Wall -g   -c -o ll.o ll.c
In file included from ll.c:3:0:
ll.h:8:5: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
ll.h:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘Node’
ll.c: In function ‘getData’:
ll.c:8:18: error: expected expression before ‘LinkedList’
ll.c:12:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c: In function ‘getSize’:
ll.c:21:12: error: expected expression before ‘LinkedList’
ll.c: In function ‘deleteNode’:
ll.c:26:18: error: expected expression before ‘LinkedList’
ll.c:32:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:37:12: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
ll.c:38:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:40:12: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
ll.c: In function ‘add’:
ll.c:52:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:54:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c: In function ‘freeList’:
ll.c:61:18: error: expected expression before ‘LinkedList’
ll.c:62:18: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:65:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:67:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ll.c:62:11: warning: variable ‘next’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ll.c:60:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
ll.c: In function ‘main’:
ll.c:85:6: error: ‘LinkedList’ has no member named ‘add’
ll.c:91:10: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
ll.c:91:10: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
ll.c: In function ‘getSize’:
ll.c:22:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
make: *** [ll.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Kill all the `typedef`s if you're using C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly define a function pointer in struct, which takes struct as a pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838963/how-to-properly-define-a-function-pointer-in-struct-which-takes-struct-as-a-poi).  The second part of the question is about a recursive structure just like the one in this question.  There may be other duplicates too.

Comment: Since the code is being compiled with a C compiler and looks like C, I've removed the C++ tag.  It is seldom correct to include both tags on a question — they are different languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
typedef struct Node{
     void *data;
     struct Node *next; // note here
     struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Comment: In your code, doesn't "typedef" create an alias called "Node" for the type "struct Node"? If so, is it legal to refer to Node (when we mean struct Node" in the body of the struct Node definition?

Answer (score 2):

You either need forward declaration, or you need to drop the typedef. You can also use typedef with having the Node twice.

#### Forward declaration

```
typedef struct Node Node; // Necessary in C, harmless (but non-idiomatic) in C++

typedef struct {
    void *data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
} Node;
```

#### No typedef (Will only work in C++, not C)

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

#### Using typedef with tag

Works in C and C++, but non-idiomatic for C++.

```
typedef struct Node {
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Good catch, I thought we would discuss C++ in here, but since you removed that tag after all, I updated my post according to your wish!

Answer (score 0):

Posting an Answer for the next reader brought here by Google searching:
`error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`

Remember when trying to implement pseudo-code that function pointers get initialized with the name of the function without any parenthesis. Rookie mistake? Maybe, but I'm not exactly rookie (taught C/C++ Labs at university in mid 90s) and it got me. Had I typed it and not cut-n-pasted, I probably would have caught the error, as I know not to create that code...

**Example with declarations supplied for completeness:**

```
//  Static menu manager
#define MAX_SELECTIONS 4
#define MAX_PROMPT_LEN 20
typedef struct _selection {
    char prompt[MAX_PROMPT_LEN];
    void(*function) ( void );
    int fn_arg;
} SELECTION ;

typedef struct _menu {
    int id;
    int num_selections;
    SELECTION selection[MAX_SELECTIONS];
} MENU;

enum _menu_ids { MAIN_MENU, DEPOSIT_MENU, WITHDRAWL_MENU, BALANCE_MENU };
enum _menu_keys { DEPOSIT, WITHDRAWL, BALANCE, CHECKING, SAVINGS };
```

**Wrong:**

```
//  WRONG
static MENU menu[] = {
    { MAIN_MENU, 4,
        {"Perform A Deposit", goto_menu(), DEPOSIT_MENU},
        {"Perform a Withdrawl", goto_menu(), WITHDRAWL_MENU },
        {"Get Balance", goto_menu(), BALANCE_MENU },
        {"Hide Menu", menu_hide(), 0}
    }
}
```

**Correct:**

```
//  Correct
static MENU menu[] = {
    { MAIN_MENU, 4, {
        {"Perform A Deposit", goto_menu, DEPOSIT_MENU},
        {"Perform a Withdrawl", goto_menu, WITHDRAWL_MENU },
        {"Get Balance", goto_menu, BALANCE_MENU },
        {"Hide Menu", menu_hide, 0} }
    }
}
```

Particularly observant readers might notice the additional braces required to initialize the `struct`'s `array`'s members were missing in the pseudo-code. The gcc compiler was kind enough to provide a useful error:
`MENU: improper number of initializers`.